# swiftui foreach Navigation Link pop immediatly

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

Ive a problem with the new NavigationLink in my app, when i click in the button, change the page but return back immidiatly. Where I wrong?

```
NavigationLink(destination: TeamsModuleView(), tag: t.id, selection: self.$selection) {
    Button(action:  {
        self.selection = t.id //Is dynamic
        self.settings.fixtureId = t.fixtureId
        self.settings.teamHomeId = t.teams.teamHomeId
        self.settings.teamAwayId = t.teams.teamAwayId
        self.settings.teamHome = t.teams.teamHome
        self.settings.teamAway = t.teams.teamAway
    }) {
        HStack {
            Text("Go")
                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
        }
        .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
        .padding(20)
        .background(Color.init(red: 0.80, green: 0.16, blue: 0.24))
        .cornerRadius(7)
    }
    .padding([.leading, .trailing], 30)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `NavigationLink` is not supposed to contain a button, it *is* a button.

NavigationLinks *must* contain a destination and some sort of title. They *can* contain a bool binding if active or not. But no Buttons.

Everything your button action does needs to be done in other ways.

Some more code would be helpful to identify what you're trying to achieve so we can help with your code.

Comment: Hi Lilfaen, thanks for reply, ok so it's possible call a function when i click on NavigationLink? now i've pass the variable via constructor in the new view and now work correctly.

Comment: @StefanoToppi it would be great if you could share -at least- the code of TeamModuleView. Without any code i'm really able to help you because i don't really know what you need.